# Obtener status del request

Tags: javascript, http, requests, http-get

Estoy aprendiendo sobre el uso de fetch y deseo utilizarlo para consultar una URL y obtener qué código de estado tiene para posteriormente guardarlo en un tabla de la base de datos. aclaro que la url que quiero consultar está en un servidor diferente al que ejecuto el script.

uso el siguiente script pero me muestra siempre como resultado status = 0, aún cuando la página al consultarla por el navegador o por postman esta disponible. donde tengo el error?

```
const url = 'https://www.google.com';
fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors', 
    cache: 'no-cache', 
    credentials: 'omit',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
      'Cache-Control':'private',
      'Content-Encoding':'gzip',
      'Vary':'Accept-Encoding',
      'Server': 'Microsoft-ISS/10.0',
      'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319',
      'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
   } 
}).then(data => { 
    console.log("Test: "+data.status);
    console.log("Test: "+data.ok);
   
});
```

Comment: Pero donde usas el response?

Comment: google te esta bloqueando por un tema de cors, fijate en la consola y te daras cuenta

Comment: coloque google como ejemplo porque me pasa con cualquier url, lo que quiero realizar con el código es un monitoreo del estatus de un servidor. yo realizo la prueba de la petición por GET con POSTMAN y la dirección responde status=200 ok, pero con el script solo muestra status cero, soy novato en esto por eso agradezco su colaboración.

Answer (score 0):

lo que sucede es que tienes un bloqueo por parte de google (en tu caso) por CORS

mira este ejemplo:

```
const url = 'https://artstation.com';
fetch(url).then(res => { 
    console.log("Test: "+ res.status);
});
```

si intentas acceder a este dominio vas a tener el mismo problema de CORS. En tu consola aparecera:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://artstation.com/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Aunque en la pestaña Network de la consola el status sea 200.
Pero si intentas acceder a un asset en la misma pagina, el cual es un recurso que comparten si tendras el status

```
const url = 'https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/covers/images/037/498/752/20210509043114/smaller_square/dmitry-bezrodniy-dmitry-bezrodniy-title.jpg?1620552674';
fetch(url).then(res => { 
    console.log("Test: "+ res.status);
});
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, no hay forma de evitar el bloqueo por CORS con javascript, sin realizar cambios en el servidor de consulta?